# Advice on iPhone Horizental UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, swipe

I'm trying to create a UIScrollView (horizental) where the user can swipe through images left and right as seen in this photo (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvtOr.jpg), where tapping on a photo would trigger an event.

I just need general advice on how to structure this programmatically, would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[Scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(Scroller.frame.size.width*4,Scroller.frame.size.height)];
```